# Can chrome.storage save "advanced" objects like Date or Map?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I made a chrome extension that manages internet history, browser cookies, etc. I'm trying to make a notification if you don't run it for a week, so I used `chrome.storage` to save the timestamp whenever you use the extension.

---

Here's my code:

<popup.js>

```
function clear()
{
chrome.browsingData.removeHistory({"since":0}, callback);
var now = new Date();
chrome.storage.local.set({key: now}, function() {
console.log('Value is set to ' + now)
}
```

(callback is an empty function)

---

<background.js>

```
chrome.storage.local.get(["key"], function(result) {
alert (result.key)
});
```

---

When I tested this, it gave me:

```
[object Object]
```

Why is this code giving me this, not the timestamp I saved?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### JSON types

In Chrome/chromium, `chrome.storage`, just like [extension messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging), supports only JSON-compatible types:

- numbers but not `BigInt`
- strings
- boolean `true` and `false`
- `null` but not `undefined`
- objects/arrays consisting of the above simple types

  - can be nested
  - can't have circular self-references
  - the keys must be strings not `Symbol`
  - the unsupported portion will be stripped so a complex type will produce `{}`

It doesn't support DOM elements, function, Set, Map, RegExp, Date, and so on.
These will be stored as `{}`.

It doesn't support [toJSON()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#tojson_behavior) customization methods, so if you want to use those you'll have to store `JSON.stringify(obj)` and call `JSON.parse(str)` when reading.

#### Solution for Date

Store Date.now() which is a number:

```js
chrome.storage.local.set({foo: Date.now()})
```

To recreate a date:

```js
chrome.storage.local.get('foo', data => {
   const date = new Date(data.foo);
   // use it here
})
```

#### Solution for Set/Map

Storing:

```js
chrome.storage.local.set({foo: [...map]})
```

Reading:

```js
chrome.storage.local.get('foo', data => {
   const map = new Map(data.foo);
   // use it here
})
```

#### Alternatives for media objects

- Convert to a data URI string.
- Convert to ArrayBuffer and store in **IndexedDB**.

P.S. Don't use `+` to concatenate strings and objects in console.log. Use `,` like this: `console.log('Value is set to', now)`

Comment: How would you store a MediaStream object?
derived from navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})
returns asynchronously a MediaStream object

Comment: Streams can't be stored but you can extract the contents as a data URI or ArrayBuffer.